# Display "Loading : Progress Bar " in Android Intent till Data Load

Tags: android

I am working on an android app, in that app i have intent2 which on click redirects to intent3 and takes some time then loads a table and displays server data into it.

Sometimes if there is a lot of data, it tales pretty much time to get the dataload and the time blank screen is displayed increases.

i wish to show a loading bar till the data loads.

how can i show the ProgrssBar till only when data is not displayed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your best bet would be to use AsyncTask in your "intent3":

You could do it like this:

```
private class performBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void>  
      {
               private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(ClassName.this);

               protected void onPreExecute()
               {
                   Dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                   Dialog.show();
               }

               protected void onPostExecute(Void unused)    
               {
                   try
                   {
                       if(Dialog.isShowing())
                       {
                           Dialog.dismiss();
                       }
                               // do your Display and data setting operation here
                   }
                   catch(Exception e)
                   {

                   }

            @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
            {
           // Do your background data fetching here 
               return null;   
        }
      }
```

Comment: I can not extend AsyncTask as i am already extending Activity Class.

Comment: This is supposed to be an inner class, hence the private. You can then call this in your onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to run an AsyncTask on onCreate when you open the new activity, the structure of the asynctask would be like this (taken from the google [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)), notice that if you want to increament a progress bar you have to implement onProgressUpdate and call publishProgress in the doInBackground method

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

 protected void onPreExecute()
 {
     // show your progress bar   
 }

 protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
     // do your work and publish the progress
     publishProgress(progress);
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
     //dismiss your progress bar
 }

}
```

This code is just an example, of course you need to adapt it to your logic/code.

Check out this simple and complete [example](http://www.android10.org/index.php/forums/43-view-layout-a-resource/908-tutorial-progressbar-running-in-asynctask)